# Toilet Paper US 6,709,762 B1

Tags: legal-status, us6709762b1

Has [US 6,709,762 B1](https://www.google.com/patents/US6709762) expired or is it still active?

Can you provide the original paperwork for this patent?

Answer (score 1):

If you examine the metadata for this patent on Google Patents, you'll see that it has a PCT Number `PCT/JP2000/000585`, indicating that the original application was filed in Japan, and that this is a PCT application (worldwide).

A PCT application has a search phase and a national phase, and the information regarding the application status in individual countries may be found in [PatentScope](https://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/detail.jsf?docId=WO2000045689) (via [WO 2000/045689 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2000045689A1), the WIPO application).

You'll find the following National Phase information:

```
Australia                 07.08.2001  23251/00    Granted:   29.04.2004
China                     03.02.2000  00803377.3   
European Patent Office    29.08.2001  2000902068  Published: 28.11.2001
                                                  Withdrawn: 27.01.2005
United States of America  02.08.2001  09890247
```

Note that the European application was withdrawn, so you need only need to determine the status of the US, Australian and Chinese applications. Although the patent was filed from a Japanese application (JP 11/27294), it appears that coverage was not sought in Japan during the national phase. I'm not familiar with Japan's patent system, so someone may need to correct me there.

On Google Patents, under Legal Events:

```
Date           Code   Event Description
Aug 29, 2007   FPAY   Fee payment   
                      Year of fee payment: 4
Nov 7, 2011    REMI   Maintenance fee reminder mailed   
Mar 23, 2012   LAPS   Lapse for failure to pay maintenance fees 
May 15, 2012   FP     Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee 
                      Effective date: 20120323
```

So, the US patent has lapsed (effective March 23, 2012) due to a failure to pay the maintenance fee. I should note that the source of this information is originally [USPTO Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair), then via IFI/Fairview Research, to Google Patents.

The information for the Australian patent grant is available via [AusPat](http://pericles.ipaustralia.gov.au/ols/auspat/applicationDetails.do?applicationNo=2000023251):

```
Vol/Iss  Publication date  Publication action                       Reason
20/36    2006-09-21        Patent Ceased                            Application Ceased  
18/18    2004-05-13        Letters Patent Sealed - Standard Patents         
18/1     2004-01-08        Applications Accepted        
14/38    2000-10-26        Applications OPI
```

So the Australian patent grant ceased on September 21, 2006.

For completeness, I would provide the status of the [Chinese patent](http://search.sipo.gov.cn/sipo/zljs/hyjs-yx-new.jsp?leixin=fmzl&recid=00803377.3), but the [SIPO](http://english.sipo.gov.cn/application/) application search is currently inaccessible for some reason.

Comment: The original Japanese application H11-027294 (from which priority is claimed by the PCT) was granted as JP 3352421 B on 20 September 2002. However, I don't know of any good way to check if the renewal fees have been paid since then.

Comment: @Ex-examiner Thank you for providing the additional information on the Japanese Patent. Where did you find it?

Comment: It's from the Japanese version of the JPO's [J-PlatPat online register](https://www.j-platpat.inpit.go.jp/web/all/top/BTmTopPage). For some reason, the English version seems to hide the status information of Japanese patents.

Comment: @vallismortis  Why do you refer to this as an application when it is a granted US patent?

Comment: @EricShain That was a mistake. I revised the answer to make a clearer distinction between the application and the patent.

Comment: @vallismortis  You still refer to it as an application in the first sentence of your answer. It would be great if you fixed that.

Comment: @EricShain Done.